# How to find a child with the parent's id in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I've read the documentation for Laravel 5.1 but I couldn't find (or understand) a way to get a child with a parent's id. I could do it with the query builder like this:

```
$child = \DB::table('children_table')->where('parent_id', $parent->id)->first();
```

But the problem with that is that it returns a stdClass, which I can't use later to update a belongsTo relationship.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Would a `child` typically have a `hasMany` relationship with `parents`? If so, call the relationship, and if you want a *specific* parent, combine a where. `$child->parent()->find($parent->id);`, assuming the relation names are fairly standard.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you're trying to get a `child` in your example though. Since you are fetching a record from the `parents_table`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually meant `children_table`, I'll edit that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're getting at, but you could try this:

**In your Parent class:**

```
class Parent extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Child');
    }
```

**In your Child class:**

```
class Child extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Parent');
    }
```

Then, you should be able to do something like:

```
App\Parent::with('children')->find($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query builder methods like `where` on an Eloquent model

> Since Eloquent models are query builders, you should review all of the
>   methods available on the query builder. You may use any of these
>   methods in your Eloquent queries.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models

See the section titled **Adding Additional Constraints**.